# Batch processing of messages from rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I need to implement batch loading of messages into the database. I figured out how to read a few messages (prefetch), but I can't figure out how I can understand 
that the message received by me is the last one in the queue and no longer needs to be expected (this situation occurs when the value of prefetch != the number of messages 
in the queue).

Advise me please how to solve this problem. I use the 
[SelectConnection](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/adapters/select.html?highlight=Select%20Connection%20Adapter) adapter from the pika library to connect to rabbitmq.